# How can I obtain search results in English with Google Place Geocomplete?

Tags: javascript, google-places-autocomplete, geocomplete

My problem is:

Place names are written in different ways depending on the Geolocation, i.e. "Majorca" in Spanish is "Mallorca".

Is there a way to codify the results of a search so that, if the user types "Mallorca" (in their own language) in the search box, the results automatically relate to the English equivalent "Majorca"? Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, if anyone need, I've did it in this way:

1. Get de PLACE ID
2. Then call api url with PLACE ID value

   ```
               $("myInput").geocomplete({
               map: ".map_canvas",
               details: "form ",
               detailsAttribute: "data-geo",
               location: center
           }).bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
               var locAPI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=[MY API KEY]&language=en&place_id="+result.place_id;

               $.ajax({
                   type: "GET", 
                   url: locAPI,
                   success: function(data){    
                   data.results[0].address_components.forEach(function(item, index) {
                           item.types.forEach(function(type, index) {
                               if (type === 'country') {
                                   $("#MYCOUNTRYFIELD").val(item.long_name);
                               }
                               if (type === 'locality') {
                                   $("#MYCITYFIELD").val(item.long_name);
                               }
                               if (type === 'administrative_area_level_1') {
                                   $("#MYSTATEFIELD").val(item.long_name);
                               }
                           });
                       });
                   }
               });

           });
   ```

This work for me, if anyone have a better solutions are welcome :)